# Hindi speech to text using sphinx4 in java

Tags: java, speech-to-text, sphinx4

I am using Sphinx4 to convert speech to text, it works fine for English, but how can I use it for Hindi speech.
For example i said "Mera name amit hai".
After converting to text the output should be "मेरा नाम अमित है"

Comment: have you got the speech to text converter for Hindi? I have the same requirement can you guide, How did you implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Hindi acoustic model to use it with sphinx4 here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hindiasr/files/Hindiasr/HindiASR-2.0/

However, it's in a very basic state and it's unlikely it will have high accuracy. For better accuracy you might want to try an acoustic model yourself, see the tutorial for details

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

The setup of the model in Eclipse is simple:

1) download the latest code as described in the tutorial:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

2) Open transcriber demo and edit path to the acoustic model and the dictionary to point to models downloaded from hindiasr

3) Create a grammar or a language model as described in lm tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm

4) Replace the file for recognition in TranscriberDemo.java.

5) Run and see it recognizes the file

Comment: thankyou nikolay shmyrev....I already searched about HindiASR-2.0 but i don't know how to configure it? i tried but failed. Is there any video about it ? or if possible please tell me step by step process to run and configure this HindiASR-2.0 in Myecllipse.

Comment: hi.. I tried but there is a problem in the  import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.WordResult; the sphinx does not have this api. there is folder of sphinx which have all the API's java file but not the class file I also tried to compile the java file to get the class file . but it shows error in all file except Configuration.java file.

Comment: It should work out of box, you checkout the sources, import them as a project into Eclipse and compile them. Try again and don't do anything yourself. Provide more information on what you have done and what issue do you face.

Comment: I imported as a project into Eclipse and the Transcriber working fine. But i don't know which files or folders in HindiASR are for acoustic model and the dictionary.

Comment: Model folder is hindi/model_parameters/hindi.cd_cont_1000. Dictionary is hindi/etc/hindi.dic

Comment: It gives an error Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'acousticModelLoader' property:'location' - Can't locate resource:/models/acoustic/hindi.cd_count_1000

Comment: and Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'null' property:'null' - java.io.FileNotFoundException: models\acoustic\hindi.cd_count_1000\means (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: You need to specify the path properly, it can be either a full path or a path to the resource within class path, relative path can also work but you need to make sure that relative path is specified agains your current working directory.

Comment: I set the path properly its working but it gives an error due to feat.params file. There is no feat.params file in HindiASR. HindiASR also have a feat folder but this empty.  Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'null' property:'null' - java.io.FileNotFoundException: models\acoustic\hindi.cd_cont_1000\feat.params (The system cannot find the file specified)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: models\acoustic\hindi.cd_cont_1000\feat.params (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Create empty feat.params in a model folder.

Comment: Hi Amit, great you got it working! But I want to know, have you tested the accuracy of the acoustic model @NikolayShmyrev suggested?